# $\exists E\in\mathcal{X}$ such that $\mu(E)<\infty$ and $\int_X|f|d\mu<\int_E|f|d\mu + \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f$ is integrable on space X, then $\forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists E\in\mathcal{X}$ such that $\mu(E)<\infty$ and $\int_X|f|d\mu<\int_E|f|d\mu + \epsilon$

To prove this somehow I need to show $lim\int_X|f|d\mu -\int_{E_n}|f|d\mu=0$ where $E_n$ increases to $E$ I guess. But how to define $E_n$. Or there is another way better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$E_n=\{x\in X\mid |f(x)|\leqslant n\}$$

Comment: But then $lim E_n = X$ so 0 or small measured sets will be included also. I think that what is asked or maybe I am interpreting the statement wrong?

Comment: Except that you choose $E=E_n$ for *a single specific* $n$, not the limit of $E_n$ when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: why does En has finite measure?